# editing a batch file from shortcut causes the path of the shortcut to change

Tags: batch-file

I've encountered a strange situation and I cant find any information for why it's keep happenning.
My enviorment: I got couple of terminals servers in my domain. I got all the users profiles stored in a diffrent "Main-server". When a user logs in there is a startup script that runs and copy the icons for the user-desktop to its currnet session from the "Main server". One of this icons is a shortcut to a batch file. The batch file itself is located in each of the Terminals servers, and the path for the shortcut is "C:\1st-dir\2nd-dir\run-script.bat".

The strange situation: When I press right-click on the shortcut and choose "Edit", the batch file itself is openned - no supprises here. I then close the file with no changes but now I see that the path for the shortcut have changed, and it's now go to "\\Terminal-serverX\C$\1st-dir\2nd-dir\run-script.bat". Even thou I got couple of terminals servers, it's keep reffering to the same one. I repeated this on diffrent shortcuts and got the same result.

Anyone know why does this happen ?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. The shortcut can only refer to one place...the file it originally pointed to.

Answer (score 2):

Looking closely at your post, the original `C:` got changed to `\\Terminal-serverX\C$` when you used the short-cut.

It sounds like 'automated shortcut resolution' might be going on.

From the Microsoft page [Disabling Automatic Network Shortcut Resolution](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/150215)

> When you create a shortcut to a resource on a mapped network drive, and then remap the same drive to a different network resource, Windows attempts to connect to the original network resource when you access the shortcut.
>
> Furthermore, when you re-establish the original connection, a different drive letter may be mapped to the original resource. This may cause programs to fail because the expected drive mappings are not present.

(I can't tell from your question what OS you are using, and admitedly that page only refers to Windows 95 and NT - so the details might be slightly different for a newer Windows version, but it does look very much like what you described)